# Read measured values via Modbus TCP from Bender PEM353 meters which are connected with Bender Comtraxx465ip using Beckhoff PLC

Tags: twincat, modbus-tcp

I want to read measured values from different registers of three different Bender PEM353 meters which are connected with Bender comtraxx465 gateway. In this system, Modbus TCP/IP protocol is considered to transfer the data from gateway to Beckhoff PLC.
The gateway is working as Modbus server and Beckhoff PLC is working as Modbus client.
Here is the code, I am tring to execute to read the data from the gateway.

```
FUNCTION_BLOCK FB_ReadInputRegister
VAR
    fbReadInputReister: FB_MBReadInputRegs;
    arrData : ARRAY [1..3] OF WORD;
    nQuantity: WORD := 3;
    nMBAddr: WORD:=0;
    
    fbTrigger : R_TRIG;
    nReadState : (WAIT, TRIGGER, READ);
    
    
END_VAR
```

```
fbTrigger();
IF fbTrigger.Q THEN
    IF nReadState = WAIT THEN
        nReadState := TRIGGER;
    END_IF
END_IF
CASE nReadState OF
    WAIT : 
            //Do nothing
    TRIGGER :
            fbReadInputReister(
                sIPAddr:= '134.102.154.7', 
                nTCPPort:= 502, 
                nUnitID:=40, 
                nQuantity:= nQuantity, 
                nMBAddr:= nMBAddr, 
                cbLength:= SIZEOF(arrData), 
                pDestAddr:= ADR(arrData), 
                bExecute:= TRUE, 
                tTimeout:= T#5S, 
                bBusy=> , 
                bError=> , 
                nErrId=> , 
                cbRead=> );
                    
            nReadState := READ; 
              
    READ :
         fbReadInputReister(bExecute := FALSE);
         IF NOT fbReadInputReister.bBusy OR fbReadInputReister.bError THEN
             nReadState := WAIT;
         END_IF
END_CASE
```

How can I read the measured values. I am facing problem with the configuration of unit id, modbus address and bit confused of comtraxx gateway register address. what should be the modbus address?

Comment: I would start to learn from Beckhoff information system, under Modbus TCP library. For example [FB_MBReadRegs](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tf6250_tc3_modbus_tcp/192755467.html&id=2806111451295813695). Please try to search yourself and then ask a specific question if you have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

According to the references that you gave the `comtraxx465` gateway can be a modbus TCP Server to relay data of PEM353 connected to it.
(so you plc will be a client who read data not a server)

The modbus registers seems to be well documented [page 39 and following](https://www.optec.ch/fr/telechargements?cmd=download&downloadid=1064&file=Cintreuse%20COM465IP%20manuel%20anglais)

A general approach is to divide the commissioning in order to earn time:

1. Wire your gateway and ping it from a PC
2. Use a PC based tool to check communication and documentation understanding ( like [ModbusDoctor](https://www.kscada.com/modbusdoctor.html))
3. Bring the PLC in the communication (only when your are able to read your data in step 2)

For the PLC communication [FB_MBReadInputRegs (code 4)](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tf6250_tc3_modbus_tcp/192755467.html&id=2806111451295813695) and [FB_MBReadRegs (code 3)](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tf6250_tc3_modbus_tcp/192755467.html&id=2806111451295813695)  can be use but going further depends on what you want to do

Please give more details on your progress to get more help

Comment: The problem I am facing to read the data from the comtraxx gateway via modbus tcp where my laptop is using as client. My system setup is like three pem353 are connected with comtraxx 465ip gateway and from the gateway, i am trying to read value using from gateway. But not able to read it directly following the second step that you mentioned because the gateway is connected to the another network. But through plc it is possible.